# Programmatically Added XsltListViewWebPart in SP2013 looks like SP2010

Tags: 2013

I'm adding XsltListViewWebPart programmatically like so:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart listViewWebpart = (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart)webPart;
listViewWebpart.InplaceSearchEnabled = true;
listViewWebpart.ClientRender = true;
listViewWebpart.IsClientRender = false;
listViewWebpart.ServerRender = false;
listViewWebpart.PartImageLarge = "/_layouts/15/images/itdl.png?rev=23";
listViewWebpart.CatalogIconImageUrl = "/_layouts/15/images/itdl.png?rev=23";
SPList list = manager.Web.GetList(manager.ServerRelativeUrl);
listViewWebpart.GhostedXslLink = "main.xsl";
listViewWebpart.ListId = list.ID;
manager.AddWebPart(listViewWebpart, this.ZoneID, this.ZoneIndex);
listViewWebpart.View.JSLink = "clienttemplates.js";
listViewWebpart.View.XslLink = "main.xsl";
listViewWebpart.View.Toolbar = "Standard";
manager.SaveChanges(listViewWebpart);
```

But, whatever I've tried it ends up looking like the following:
[image: Example]

I was under impression that JSLink or XslLink or ClientRender might help me, but nothing really does. I've also compared the differences between resulting  markup for the 'ugly' web part and a 'good-looking' one in SharePoint Designer and found no obvious clues as to what might be wrong.

Help would be really appreciated

Comment: Adding web part = SP2010 way. In SP2013 those controls are app parts, that is something totally different. See here to add a clientwebpart programaticallY: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91435/how-to-add-client-web-part-to-aspx-page-programmatically-in-sharepoint-provider

Comment: The XsltListViewWebPart is NOT an App Part, it is a good old server-side built-in web part. An App Part is something completely different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably it occurs since list view *still* uses XSLT rendering mode when web part is added via SharePoint SSOM.

Use `ViewId` and `XmlDefinition` properties to specify *explicitly* which list view is used for rendering.

Below is provided the complete example for adding XsltListViewWebPart web part in SharePoint 2013:

```
private static void AddListViewWebPart(SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm,string listTitle,string zoneId,int zoneIndex)
{
   var list = wpm.Web.Lists.TryGetList(listTitle);
   var view = list.GetUncustomizedViewByBaseViewId(1);
   var wp = new XsltListViewWebPart();
   wp.InplaceSearchEnabled = true;
   wp.ClientRender = true;
   wp.ListId = list.ID;
   wp.ViewId = int.Parse(view.BaseViewID);
   wp.XmlDefinition = view.GetViewXml();
   wpm.AddWebPart(wp, zoneId, zoneIndex);
}
```

> Note: For example, for Pages library, when `ViewId` and
>   `XmlDefinition` properties are omitted, list view (BaseViewId = 0) is
>   rendered which in turn used XSLT as a rendering mode.

Key Points:

- Set `ClientRender` property to true in order to render list view
  using CSR rendering mode
- Specify `ViewId` and `XmlDefinition` properties to render the proper
  list view

**Example**

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        var pageFile = web.GetFile(pageUrl);
        var wpm = pageFile.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        AddListViewWebPart(wpm, "Pages", "Main", 1);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Vadim, thank you so much! It works perfectly. I've virtually spent hours and hours pulling my hair over this problem. I hope it's going to be a very useful answer for others too.

Comment: Vadim , Currently m Using Your Code ,but Facing Error:"The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."

Comment: This code should be run in feature receiver to setup page webparts during activation