# Site Columns JSLink doesn't work in custom XSLTListViewWebPart

Tags: javascript, visual-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part, jslink

I have a site column (Status) that I've added JSLink to, that runs my custom JavaScript. This works fine on lists. The JavaScript changes the text to a colored image.

I've then created a Visual Web Part that has some custom functionality, one of which is that I'm adding a `XsltListViewWebPart` from within the code behind.

```
 XsltListViewWebPart lvwp = new XsltListViewWebPart();
 lvwp.WebId = elevatedWeb.ID;
 lvwp.ListId = List.ID;
 lvwp.JSLink = "/_layouts/15/JS/jquery-2.1.1.min.js|/_layouts/15/JS/JSLinkFields.js";                        
 lvwp.ServerRender = false;
 lvwp.ClientRender = true;
 var view = list.GetUncustomizedViewByBaseViewId(1);
 lvwp.ViewId = int.Parse(view.BaseViewID);

 string organisationalFilter = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"internalName\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + department + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
 lvwp.XmlDefinition = "<View BaseViewID='1'>" +
           "<Query>" + organisationalFilter + "</Query>" +
              "<ViewFields>" +
                  "<FieldRef Name=\"Status\" />" +
              "</ViewFields>" +
           "</View>";

  lvwp.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
  lvwp.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;

  ListViewWebPartPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(lvwp);
```

I've set a `debugger;` in javascript and when I load the list, the script works. However when I load the Web Part, nothing happens.

From searching the web, I've come across some tips but nothing has really worked. Such as adding `lvwp.ServerRender = False;`and adding the JSLink to the Webpart (`lvwp.JSLink = "";`)

Would be great to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this behavior could be related with JavaScript template itself. It seems that when XLV web part is instantiated via Visual web part, custom template is not applied since `clienttemplates.js` (part of CSR library) library is not yet loaded.

In order to make sure the custom template is registered property, try to enclose it using SP.SOD.executeFunc function as shown below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      OnPreRender: function(ctx) {
          console.log('PreRender event is triggered');
      },


      OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
         console.log('PostRender event is triggered');
      }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but this could be the problem:

```
lvwp.JSLink = "~site/_layouts/15/JS/jquery2.1.1.min.js|~site/_layouts/15/JS/JSLinkFields.js";
```

I think you should remove the `~site` part from the URL:s, like this:

```
lvwp.JSLink = "/_layouts/15/JS/jquery2.1.1.min.js|/_layouts/15/JS/JSLinkFields.js";
```

Also make sure to set the `ClientRender` property to `true` on the webpart:

```
lvwp.ClientRender = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried that with no luck. Aswell as:
•~sitecollection
•~siteLayouts
•~siteCollectionLayouts

Comment: I found another thing missing, check my revised answer

Comment: I'm currently looking a this post: but the cliendRender = true; did not do anything.http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119266/programmatically-added-xsltlistviewwebpart-in-sp2013-looks-like-sp2010